# How to order list of positions for a linerenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in Unity3D an am trying to draw a border based on an image. The code finds a set of positions that are the edges, and saves them in two lists, one for the x cords, one for the y cords. Now I want to input these coordinates into a LineRenderer, which would draw a line between every point you put into it. But, this creates a giant mess. This is because of the order of the coordinates: first every point with the same x-coordinate, then the next x-coordinate, etc. This generates a huge mess: lots of unconnected horizontal lines that are then connected by diagonal lines by the Unity software...

So what I am looking for: what algoritm or function can I use that I can input into my points, and returns the correct order of the points (so either a right-handed stroll through all the points or a left-handed stroll) so I can put it into the linerenderer. Every point has at least one neighbour that is also in the list, but if allowing backtracking is too hard I can remove that so each point has at least two neighbours in the lists.

Below a bit of my code:

```
List<int> xs = new List<int>();
List<int> ys = new List<int>();
for loops that fill the lists, identical index means the points belong together
var orderedpoints = OrderPointsForLineRenderer(xs,ys);
...
```

Comment: Are you talking about a concave hull algorithm?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Now I know what to search for!!